# Regex matching string that doesn't end with any of multiple options

Tags: regex

I'm a complete neophyte at this, but I'm essentially trying to write a regex to redirect a website automatically.

I'm trying to get imgur to always redirect to grid view, and I got stuck.

So far, I have got `^https?://imgur\.com/a/((?!.*/layout/grid$).*)` redirecting to `https://imgur.com/a/$1/layout/grid`. This was the only way I could get it to not get stuck and add multiple lines to the end of the url, by specifying that the string must end with `/layout/grid/`.

I'm essentially stuck in that sometimes, the album url has some extraneous stuff at the end, which needs to be gotten rid off. For example, `https://imgur.com/a/L7D9i#0`. I need to get rid of the # and everything after it before I can add on the `/layout/grid/`, or it doesn't work. I tried to split it into two, but I can't figure out how to get the expression to match a string that doesn't end with either `layout/grid` or `#\d`. This is as far as I got, but it doesn't work: `^https?://imgur\.com/a/(?!(/layout/grid$|.*#\d$).*)`

Sorry if this is ridiculously basic or something, I don't actually know regex, and everything I managed was from google, so I don't even well understand the syntax I'm using.

Comment: Your syntax is good, but you have it matching the `/` between `http://imgur.com/a` and `layout/grid` twice. So: `^https?://imgur\.com/a/(?!(layout/grid$|.*#\d$).*)`

Comment: What is the context in which the regex is being used? Does it supply a variable for the URI without the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is written differently from when you just had the `/layout/grid`. By which I mean, a parentheses is shifted and a `.*` is missing. The proper expression would be this:

```
^https?://imgur\.com/a((?!.*/layout/grid$).*)(?=#)
```

The original expression doesn't even appear to try to shave it off; it causes the match to fail if it has the `#`. Although, if that was what you wanted, use this:

```
https?://imgur\.com/a((?!(.*/layout/grid$|.*#)).*)
```